# How do I calculate date to not allow dates smaller than the current day?

Tags: javascript, date

I am making a business rule in which the customer's checkin can never be less than the previous day. but I'm just finding the difference between the days, in which case the values ​​are the same for later days and previous days, for example:

```
Current day: 11/02/2021
Checkin: 10/02/2021
Result: 1 day

Current day: 11/02/2021
Checkin: 02/12/2021
Result: 1 day
```

```js
function calcularData(dataAtual, checkIn) {
  
  const dataatual = new Date(inverterData(dataAtual));
  const checkin = new Date(inverterData(checkIn));
  const timeDiff = Math.abs(checkin.getTime() - dataatual.getTime());
  const diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
  return diffDays
}
  
function inverterData(date) {
  const regex = '^([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})';
  const dataFormatada = date.match(regex);

  return `${dataFormatada[2]}/${dataFormatada[1]}/${dataFormatada[3]}`;
}

console.log(calcularData('11022021','10012021'))
```

Checkin: 02/12/2021
Result: 1 day

Comment: Why do you `Math.abs()`?

Comment: get rid of the getTime() in timeDifff.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is using *Math.abs* for the days difference, so negative values become positive.

When getting days difference with whole dates, *Math.round* should be used so that small differences caused by daylight saving changes are filtered out. *ceil* will fix cases where a day is shorter than 24 hrs, but not longer. *round* fixes both.

Also, your method of parsing could be very much more efficient. Much better to get the values from the timestamp and pass them directly to the Date constructor than create another string that is then parsed by the internal parser, e.g.

```js
// Return difference in days
function calcularData(s1, s2) {
  // Parse timestamp in ddmmyyyy format to Date
  let parse = s => new Date(s.substr(4,4), s.substr(2,2) - 1, s.substr(0,2));
  return Math.round((parse(s2) - parse(s1)) / 8.64e7);
}

console.log(calcularData('11022021','10012021')) // -32

console.log(calcularData('11022021','10022021')) // -1

console.log(calcularData('11022021','12022021')) //  1
```